# Wrong release issue

Tags: beamer, errors

I am trying to use the animate package, but whenever I include it I get the error

You have requested release '2020-10-1' of LaTeX, but only release '2020-02-02' is available.

I am using MikTex and TexMaker(Which I reinstalled) I also went onto the MikTex console to get all the package updates.

How do I go about solving this, I want to use a GIF in a Beamer presentation and animate seems to be the only viable option.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should update `ltxbase` (probably in admin and user mode)

Comment: Your latex is too old. Ensure that you update in user *and* admin mode.